# Add the classes after 2 loops on react using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add the classes after 2 loops. It's working but can't hide `{x++}` text. How can hide this? I have also tried with using the index.

```
const workdata = this.state.worksData.map((work, index) => (
            <div
                className={
                    x % 3 == 0
                        ? "col-lg-4 col-md-6 offset-lg-0 offset-md-3"
                        : "col-lg-4 col-md-6"
                }
                key={index}
            >
                <div
                    className={
                        x % 3 == 0 ? "single-box" : "single-box with-line"
                    }
                >
                    <span>{work.position}</span>
                </div>
                {x++}
            </div>
        ));
```

using for loop and it works.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (x % 3 == 0) {
            console.log("Class", data[i]);
        } else {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
        x++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use existing index property instead of creating new x. Please see below sample code

```
const workdays = this.state.worksData.map((work, index) => (
            <div
                className={
                    (index + 1) % 3 == 0
                        ? "col-lg-4 col-md-6 offset-lg-0 offset-md-3"
                        : "col-lg-4 col-md-6"
                }
            >
                <div
                    className={
                        (index + 1) % 3 == 0 ? "single-box" : "single-box with-line"
                    }
                >
                    <span>{work.position}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        ));
```

Comment: I wanted the class to add after two loops. `like the 3rd item, 6th item, 9th item`. Can you do that?

Comment: Yes, just put (index+1) % 3 == 0. It will behave the same as you have implemented already using for loop.